# Android layout displaying wrong

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have designed a screen and all are in dp or match_parent or wrap_content. Which means in any screen regardless of resolution or screen size, correct me if wrong.

(Nexus 4)
[image: BOA]

and it comes out like this (Nexus 5)

[image]

This is the XML code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.techiequickie.bharath.parsetest.PlaceBet">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="BOA"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffbf0c16" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_action"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff98cb00"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_action"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff98cb00"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_action"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff98cb00"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_action"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff98cb00"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="New"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="My Bets"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Earnings"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Account"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`correct me if wrong`. **WRONG**.

The Nexus4 is an **xhdpi** device, while the Nexus5 is an **xxhdpi** device.

This means that - if you didn't provide the properly scaled graphics for both -  Android will perform the scaling for you.

It seems that `you provided the lower graphics` resources, so Android scales **UP-wards**, introducing pixellation (fake pixels) or stretching.

If you want to save on the graphics resource count, you should **at least** provide the **higher resolution** graphics, so Android will scale **DOWN-wards**, averaging the pixel colours.

In addition, the correct unit for `android:textSize` is **sp**, not **dp**.

Comment: but I do have the appropriate images for xxhdpi. Isn't the IDE automatically supposed to pick it up from the folder?

Comment: Maybe your graphics are too big? You should always have in mind how should it be sized to be shown on an average 320*480 px 160 dpi screen (average **mdpi** phone screen), which is considered to be the unit (1px = 1dp).

Comment: is mipmap for only launcher icons?

Comment: What has a [mipmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) to do with scaling Android UI graphic resources?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73848/discussion-between-jackyboi-and-der-golem).

Answer (score 0):

You should use sp instead of dp on textSizes and also you need to put different images for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi.